# How to install CLang using precompiled binaries?

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, c++

How do I install CLang on Ubuntu, using precompiled binaries of CLang that I downloaded?

Here's how I downloaded CLang: "LLVM Download Page" -> "Download LLVM 3.2" -> "Clang Binaries for Ubuntu-12.04/x86_64" ( http://llvm.org/releases/3.2/clang+llvm-3.2-x86_64-linux-ubuntu-12.04.tar.gz .)

Then, I expanded the archive into a folder on my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-bit machine. The contents of the expanded folder look like this:

```
$ ls clang+llvm-3.2-x86_64-linux-ubuntu-12.04
bin  docs  include  lib  share
```

Question: What do I do next? Do I have to copy these into some folders myself, and if so, which ones exactly? Most instructions I found online are for building CLang from source, which doesn't apply here.

I created a basic hello-world C++ program, and was able to compile and run it, using GCC and autotools. Now, I want to compile the same program with CLang.

Also asked on StackOverflow: How to install CLang using precompiled binaries?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17045954/how-to-install-clang-using-precompiled-binaries .

Comment: Why not simply use the package manager?

Comment: I prefer to not depend on package for this purpose, because I may need to use a newer version of CLang that is available in a package.  For example, currently, the package installed by `sudo apt-get install clang` has CLang 3.0, but I want the latest available, CLang 3.2.

Comment: Backporting is an option. I backported 3.4 to Debian stable some time ago. The version in stable is 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the same step as mentioned in https://askubuntu.com/questions/89615/how-do-i-install-llvm-clang-3-0

```
tar xzf clang*
cd clang*
sudo cp -R * /usr/local/
```